# Split one big parquet file into multiple parquet files by a key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, parquet

I'd like split a big parquet file into multiple parquet files in different folder in HDFS, so that I can build partitioned table (whatever Hive/Drill/Spark SQL) on it.

Data example:

```
+-----+------+
|model|  num1|
+-----+------+
|  V80| 195.0|
|  V80| 750.0|
|  V80| 101.0|
|  V80|   0.0|
|  V80|   0.0|
|  V80| 720.0|
|  V80|1360.0|
|  V80| 162.0|
|  V80| 150.0|
|  V90| 450.0|
|  V90| 189.0|
|  V90| 400.0|
|  V90| 120.0|
|  V90|  20.3|
|  V90|   0.0|
|  V90|  84.0|
|  V90| 555.0|
|  V90|   0.0|
|  V90|   9.0|
|  V90|  75.6|
+-----+------+
```

The result folder structure should be grouped by "model" field:

```
+
|
+-----model=V80
|       | 
|       +----- XXX.parquet
+-----model=V90
|       | 
|       +----- XXX.parquet
```

I tried the script like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val conf = new SparkConf()
   case class Infos(name:String, name1:String)
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val rdd = sqlContext.read.load("hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/a_e550_parquet").select("model", "num1").limit(10000)

    val tmpRDD = rdd.map { item => (item(0), Infos(item.getString(0), item.getString(1))) }.groupByKey()

    for (item <- tmpRDD) {
      import sqlContext.implicits._
      val df = item._2.toSeq.toDF()
      df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/model=" + item._1)
    }
  }
```

Just threw out a null point exception.

Answer (score 5):

You should use partitionBy from DataFrame. You do not need groupBy. Something like below should give what you want.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/a_e550_parquet").select("model", "num1").limit(10000)
df.write.partitionBy("model").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
```

Comment: You are correct, we tried this. But it seems very slow, there are about 500M entries of records. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: There could be many reasons why this is slow. Some of the things you have to check are, is the job shuffling too much, (see if you can increase/decrease the shuffle partitions size), if there is data skew etc. It is hard to say without knowing the data. You are the right person to check this :-)